# Operation translation from jCombobox in Java to Spinner in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Asking a follow-up question here after solving some other problems I was having.

Essentially, I'm translating a working program from Java into Eclipse for development of an android app. I've whittled down the problems to a single block of code. In Java, it looked like this:

```
 private void shapeDropDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   if(shapeDropDown.getSelectedIndex()==1)
      diameterBox.setText("0");
   if(shapeDropDown.getSelectedIndex()==1)
       diameterBox.setEditable(false);
   if(shapeDropDown.getSelectedIndex()==2)
       widthBox.setText("0");
   if(shapeDropDown.getSelectedIndex()==2)
       widthBox.setEditable(false);
   if(shapeDropDown.getSelectedIndex()==2)
       heightBox.setText("0"); 
   if(shapeDropDown.getSelectedIndex()==2)
       heightBox.setEditable(false);}
```

Basically, if the user chooses a rectangle over a cylinder, the diameter input is set to "0" (so it is an integer) and is set to not editable. Or, if the user chooses cylinder, the height & width inputs were set to "0" and not editable.

However, I'm having difficulty with this method in Eclipse. Could you please show me how to implement this method in Eclipse? This is what I've got so far that is not working, thus making the entire app malfunction:

```
//Blank out the appropriate blanks:
    private void setOnItemSelectedListener (new onItemSelectedListener() {

   if (shapeDD.equals("Rectangle"))
        txtDiameter.setText("0");
    if (shapeDD.equals("Rectangle"))
        txtDiameter.setEnabled(false);
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtWidth.setEnabled(false);
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtWidth.setText("0");
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtHeight.setEnabled(false);
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtHeight.setEnabled(false);
    });
```

A secondary issue I'm having is with resetting the spinner once I'm done with it. In Java, it's simply:

```
jCombobox.setSelectedIndex(0).
```

What is the equivalent method in Eclipse for a Spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer to your second question: the equivalent method for the spinner is `setSelection(index)`, for references see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: That actually did work, thanks! Any other ideas on the first problem?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to check two times the same condition 'if (... == 1), if (... == 1)', you can make only one if statement and your code will be more clear. I don't understand on what you apply your 'setOnItemSelectedListener' method. Second, don't say 'Eclipse', be specific about what environment are you using (Java? Android?)

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it in Android using Eclipse ADK. I'm using Java in the development of the app, but I'm continuously confused with the differences between the two programs. 
And perhaps I do need to go through and clean up my code a bit, but right now I'd settle for a working app. 
Frankly I don't know any more about the "setOnItemSelectedListener" method, it was just one more iteration of the same block that didn't work. I need some sort of method like that or 'ActionPerformed' because it's not initializing as a standalone.

Comment: Should I be using an "ArrayAdapter" instead?

Comment: You need to call setOnItemSelectedListener on your Spinner

Comment: I did, as shown in the code above, but it still wasn't working. Probably doing it wrong, though. I'm thinking of just going with checkboxes instead...

Comment: Just check for some Spinner tutorials if you can't use it

Comment: I was able to successfully use checkboxes to fulfill the role of the second spinner. Thanks.